# AppleScript to set "my card" to a defined name or e-mail address in Contacts under OS X 10.12.3

Tags: macos, applescript

First i must say sorry for my bad english. I come from Germany and i can't find any help or idea for my problem in different Communitys here.

I look and try to write a little script, which one set my card to the person with email address "johndoe@...", or alternatively from the person named "John Doe"
Both is ok but i prefer email address.

I hope i can find some help here.

This only one script, which one i found doesn't work.

```
tell application "Contacts"
activate
try
set my card to people whose first name is "John" and last name is "Doe"
end try
quit
end tell
```

Thank's for help and greetings
Andy

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've already asked [in the correct place](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/273476/31378).  Please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/349071).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close

```
tell application "Contacts"
    activate
    try
        set my card to 1st person whose first name is "John" and last name is "Doe"
        save
    end try
    quit
end tell
```

You have to get the `1st` person who matches the arguments and you have to save the address book.

Or searching for email

```
tell application "Contacts"
    activate
    try
        set my card to 1st person whose value of emails contains "johnn@doe.com"
        save
    end try
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work's great. Your help makes me happy now.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank

Comment: Hello Varian, maybe i can ask you one more thing. I do a script for to clean history in Safari It works but it is not really nice way. It's only press button by button. Did you ever have heard from a script where i can do this directly? I look, but i can't find. I post my script under the answer, where you can see what i mean.

Comment: Va.. who? ;-) You can't clear the history directly, but try to quit Safari then delete everything containing `History` in `~/Library/Safari` (`~` = User Library) and relaunch Safari.

Comment: Ups...AutoCorrect...sorry. Ok thank's. Look, i try to post my script, but not right. It's like text.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Verlauf löschen …" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Verlauf" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari"
    try
        click button "Verlauf löschen" of front window of process "Safari"
    on error
        try
            click button "Verlauf löschen" of sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Safari"
        end try
    end try
end tell
tell application "Safari" to close every window
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.startpage.com/deu/#hmb"}
end tell
```